# que tengo que poner en mi front para mandar llamar la peticion

Tags: javascript, html, fetch, requests, wampserver

Estoy haciendo una petición http en javascript, el api que quiero consumir es un API privada, pero como son dominios diferentes me mandaba que esta bloqueado por la política CORS, pase mi código de js a otro archivo, osea mi back para que funcione mi petición, pero que tengo que poner tanto en el back como en el front para mandar llamar la petición.

Adjunto código:

```
var url = "https://sandbox.tesseract.mx/api/v2/institution",
       credentials = btoa();

       fetch (url,{

         method: 'GET',
        headers: new Headers({
        Set,'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS",
       "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, 
     Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization",
       "Content-Type": 'application/json',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization",
    }),
       mode : "cors"

     })
     .then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(response.error)
    }
    return response.json();
     })
      .then((result) => {
       if (result.status != 200) { throw new Error("Bad Server Response"); }
     return result.text();
      })
     .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
     })
      .catch((error) => {console.log(error);});
```

Y mi front es una hoja de html que tiene las etiquetas script, pero que debería poner en ambos para que muestre la petición, mi error era que no quería ver bien que api quería consumir, pero es un api privada, tengo el acceso para entrar a ese api, pero por el cors no podía correrlo directo, pase todo este código a un back, pero como lo mando llamar al front?.

Comment: Tienes que modificar el backend para que te acepte las peticiones

Comment: si las acepta pero tengo que mostrar su respuesta en html pero no se que  poner para que pase eso

Comment: Para usarlo en backend solo envia la petición  con curl y haz echo de la respuesta, dependiendo del tipo de respuesta la forma es la que lo mostraras en el fronted, en postman puedes ver ejemplos de curl.